# Two OS on two separate SSD

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, bios, grub

My laptop has one SSD with Win10 on it. I want to buy addition SSD M.2 and install ubuntu on it. I have few questions about this:

1. I already have experience how two setup win7+ubuntu on ONE HDD, but I faced with the problem that when I somehow break the ubuntu I also break a GRUB, so I can't start my laptop. As a result I had to format disk. Could I faced with such problem if I'll have separate SSD's?
2. When I setup two OS on one disk there was a requirement to set-up win firstly after that setup Ubuntu so GRUB can "see" windows in boot menu
3. In case of reinstalation any of OS or removing SSD. Can it cause problems with loading OS on another SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this still holds true, but in the past, Windows installations would overwrite the Grub boot loader.  This made other OSs unbootable.  I heard Microsoft is more friendly now, but I have not tested it.

If you installed Linux first, then installed Windows and it overwrites the boot loader, you can always use the Linux install media to recreate the boot loader (Grub).  This would then show both Windows and Linux as bootable options.

Personally, on my main computer, I have Linux Mint and Windows 10 on separate SSDs.  However, rather than using a shared boot loader on the first SSD, I keep them entirely separate.  I already had Windows 10 installed and added a second SSD.  I disabled the Windows disk in BIOS and installed Linux Mint on the second drive, using Grub only on that second drive.  I then reenabled the Windows disk.  When the machine boots, I hit F12 to select the boot disk and boot whichever OS I choose (your BIOS might have a different key).  This allows me to keep both operating systems completely separate from each other.  As an additional bonus, I can boot Linux Mint off the second drive inside of Windows using VirtualBox.